# Salesforce Outlook add-in missing formatting/CSS on internal network

Tags: outlook, microsoft-office

[Example Image of how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbs6N.png)

### Info

- Windows 10 1909 or newer
- Microsoft Office 2019 64-bit
- Fortigate's running 6.4.2+

We've recently started rolling out Salesforce to external locations, but for two of those, we're seeing some strange issues with the Salesforce Outlook add-in seemingly not being rendered correctly when you're on the internal network, if you switch over to the Guest network, which goes over the same internet breakout as the internal network, then it works. Also running Fiddler to debug it makes it work on the Internal network. So far I've tried packet tracing, running process monitor but neither has given me a definitive pointer to where the problem is. Also tested with different DNS, resetting the local network on the PC's, created new firewall policies with all traffic allowed, even though the same policies work at headoffice.

With Fiddler making it work, it points to it being some interception or proxy with the local computer, but there's no proxy configured for those networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is embarrasing, checking things over, and looking at [Help! Running Fiddler Fixes My App???](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/help!-running-fiddler-fixes-my-app-) make me check the Internet Options Connections again, and even though I was certain we checked this (We don't have any proxy settings, but "Automatically detect settings" was checked), removing "Automatically detect settings" made it work.

Comment: Cool! Happy to know that it works now. You can upvote the useful reply and mark your solution as answer to close this up :)

Answer (score 0):

> Also running Fiddler to debug it makes it work on the Internal network.

Searching on this leads me to the article below which I assume could be of some help:

[Help! Running Fiddler Fixes My App???](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/help!-running-fiddler-fixes-my-app-)

By the way, as regards to the Process Monitor, have you tried to run it on both the internal and the guest network, then compare the results to see if there would be any clues?

Comment: Thanks for that link, it made me check over Internet Options again, and discovered that unchecking "Automatically Detect Settings" under Connections - > LAN Settings fixes the problem.